# Error running AWS SES sample

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm trying to run the sample program here http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-using-smtp-java.html
here's the command output...

```
$ java AmazonSESSample -cp "javamail-1.4.3/mail.jar"
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/mail/Address
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
        atsun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.mail.Address
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 7 more
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main"
```

I tried to Google for answers by using this search string...

```
 search string = java mail.jar "Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again"
```

i didn't see anything useful in the search results :-(

Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so the answer is that the classpath option was AFTER the main class. So the -cp and jar value are being passed as 'args' to the 'main' method - doh!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
By simply moving this option as shown below, the jar is loaded and the class is found as expected..
A useful outcome of this frustrating puzzle is that i discovered '-verbose:class' which will be useful for other problems in the future i'm sure :)

```
$ java -verbose:class -cp '.;mail.jar' AmazonSESSample | grep Session
[Loaded javax.mail.Session from file:/C:/Users/Michael/Documents/GitHub/guesstimate/scratch/mail.jar]
[Loaded javax.mail.Session$1 from file:/C:/Users/Michael/Documents/GitHub/guesstimate/scratch/mail.jar]
[Loaded javax.mail.Session$3 from file:/C:/Users/Michael/Documents/GitHub/guesstimate/scratch/mail.jar]
[Loaded javax.mail.Session$5 from file:/C:/Users/Michael/Documents/GitHub/guesstimate/scratch/mail.jar]
[Loaded javax.mail.Session$4 from file:/C:/Users/Michael/Documents/GitHub/guesstimate/scratch/mail.jar]
[Loaded javax.mail.Session$2 from file:/C:/Users/Michael/Documents/GitHub/guesstimate/scratch/mail.jar]

Michael@mikeToshSpare /cygdrive/c/Users/Michael/Documents/GitHub/guesstimate/scratch
$ java -verbose:class AmazonSESSample -cp '.;mail.jar' | grep Session
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/mail/Session
        at AmazonSESSample.main(AmazonSESSample.java:56)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.mail.Session
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 1 more
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the JAR file (`javamail-1.4.3/mail.jar`) you indicated is not being found..

```
java AmazonSESSample -cp "javamail-1.4.3/mail.jar"
```

Try providing the full path like below (below is an example only)

```
java AmazonSESSample -cp "/usr/lib/javamail-1.4.3/mail.jar"
```

**UPDATE**: On Windows try the below

```
java AmazonSESSample -classpath "C:\Users\MichaelDocuments\GitHub\guesstimate\scratch\javamail-1.4.3\mail.jar"
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I will try to see if a fully qualified path fixes the error.

Comment: $ java AmazonSESSample -cp ".c:\Users\MichaelDocuments\GitHub\guesstimate\scratch\javamail-1.4.3\mail.jar"
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/mail/Address
    ...java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
            at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
            ... 7 more
    Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
    Exception in thread "main"

Comment: oops! i tried to fully-qualify the jar but didn't seem to improve things.

Comment: What is the "." in front of the "c:\"?

Comment: Removed :) Same result.

Comment: Also am assuming you already checked that the file `c:\Users\MichaelDocuments\GitHub\guesstimate\scratch\javamail-1.4.3\mail.jar` does exist... and is there supposed to be a `\\` between Michael and Documents in your path?

Comment: Oh that was careless of me! i updated the question by adding a screenshot of my Windows Explorer and updated the command-line...

     $ java AmazonSESSample -classpath  "c:\Users\Michael\Documents\GitHub\guesstimate\scratch\javamail-1.4.3\mail.jar"
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/mail/Address 
            ...
    Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
    Exception in thread "main"